# I'm trying to load 500Mb file (Files.readAllBytes) and I need more than 2 Gb Heap size. Why?

Tags: java

I'm trying to load 500Mb file in memory (Files.readAllBytes) and I need more than 2 Gb Heap size.

With default settings I have OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. When I set up -Xmx1000m it doesn't work. It works only if I set at least -Xmx2300m -Xmx2300m. Why do Java need such overhead?

Comment: Although I cannot answer your concrete question, it would be useful to know the type of file you are trying to read (xml?), so maybe a different approach can be suggested.

Comment: What error do you get when you do this? Is your program literally just reads the file and exists, or is it doing some other work for a while before reading the file?

Comment: Why don't you map it into memory instead (using `FileChannel.map()`)?

Comment: If your requirements aren't forcing you to hold the whole file in memory, i'd recommend reading it in chunks using Scanner or BufferedReader instead of loading it whole in memory.

Comment: What 'source' are you passing to readAllBytes?  Specifically, is it buffered?

Answer (score 2):

Two possible answers come to mind,

1. The library call that you are using is copying the bytes between buffers more than once, effectively multiplying the amount of memory that you need.
2. The heap is separated into logical parts (generations).  When allocating a 'large' object that does not fit into a generation then the object will be tenured early.  If there is not space in the old gen, then the object allocation will fail.  Combine this with 1 above, and a small heap and one can see how Java could hit trouble.

The simplest solution to both problems is to [memory map the file](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/power-of-java-memorymapped-file.html) instead, this will allocate the memory off heap and be very efficient/fast at reading the file in as it reduces the number of OS context switches and byte buffer copies involved in reading the file.

Comment: I think the first variant is very possible because direct allocation 500Mb uses about 900Mb of heap size.